# How to change values from writable basic Datatypes on an OPC UA Server with FIWARE OPC UA AGENT

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion, opc-ua

### GOAL

Change writable values on the OPC UA Server by using the Fiware OPC UA Agent.

### My test implementation

1. Adding the NodeId "7:PLC1_7:G_Communication_7:fi_heartbeat_i" to the "command" and "contextSubscription" sections in the config.json file. The value data type of the NodeId is Int16, but because this value is supposed to be written, I assume that "command" must be used as the type. Unfortunately, more detailed information cannot be found in the manual [fiware opcua agent](https://iotagent-opcua.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html).
2. Start a new test environment with OpcUa Agent, Orion Context broker and mongodb.

### Expectet behavior

The value on the server is updated when a request is sent to the Context Broker.

### Current behaviour

- The value of the parameter is read out correctly but with an incorrect data type (string instead of integer).
- The value of the parameter is not updated when a request is sent to the Orion Context Broker.

### additional informations

1. config.json

```json
     {
      "logLevel" : "DEBUG",
      "contextBroker" : {
        "host" : "orion",
        "port" : 1026
      },
      "server" : {
        "port" : 4001,
        "baseRoot" : "/"
      },
      "deviceRegistry" : {
        "type" : "memory"
      },
      "mongodb" : {
        "host" : "iotmongo",
        "port" : "27017",
        "db" : "iotagent",
        "retries" : 5,
        "retryTime" : 5
      },
      "providerUrl" : "http://iotopcua:4001",
      "pollingExpiration" : "200000",
      "pollingDaemonFrequency" : "20000",
      "deviceRegistrationDuration" : "P1M",
      "defaultType" : null,
      "browseServerOptions" : null,
      "service" : "test",
      "subservice" : "/test",  
      "types" : {
        "g_communication" : {
          "service" : "test",
          "subservice" : "/test",
          "active" : [{
            "name" : "7:PLC1_7:G_Communication_7:fo_smartControllerActive_b",
            "type" : "Boolean"
          } ],
          "lazy" : [ ],
          "commands" : [{
            "name" : "7:PLC1_7:G_Communication_7:fi_heartbeat_i",
            "type" : "Command"  
            }]
        }
      },
      "contexts" : [ {
            "id" : "plant",
            "type" : "g_communication",
            "service" : "test",
            "subservice" : "/test",
            "polling" : null,
            "mappings" : [{
              "ocb_id" : "7:PLC1_7:G_Communication_7:fo_smartControllerActive_b",
              "opcua_id" : "ns=7;s=G_Communication.fo_smartControllerActive_b",
              "object_id" : null,
              "inputArguments" : []
            } ]
      }],
      "contextSubscriptions" : [{ 
            "id" : "plant",
            "type" : "g_communication",
            "mappings" : [{
              "ocb_id" : "7:PLC1_7:G_Communication_7:fi_heartbeat_i",
              "opcua_id" : "ns=7;s=G_Communication.fi_heartbeat_i",
              "object_id" : "ns=7;s=G_Communication",
              "inputArguments" : [{
                 "type": "Number"
              }]
            }]
        }]
    }
```

2. List Entities

```sh
curl 'http://localhost:1026/v2/entities/plant/' -H 'fiware-service: test' -H 'fiwate-servicepath: /test' | python -m json.tool
 % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   684  100   684    0     0  13751      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 13959
{
   "7:PLC1_7:G_Communication_7:fi_heartbeat_i": {
       "metadata": {
           "ServerTimestamp": {
               "type": "ISO8601",
               "value": "null"
           },
           "SourceTimestamp": {
               "type": "ISO8601",
               "value": "null"
           }
       },
       "type": "string",
       "value": "4"
   },
   "7:PLC1_7:G_Communication_7:fi_heartbeat_i_info": {
       "metadata": {},
       "type": "commandResult",
       "value": " "
   },
   "7:PLC1_7:G_Communication_7:fi_heartbeat_i_status": {
       "metadata": {},
       "type": "commandStatus",
       "value": "UNKNOWN"
   },
   "7:PLC1_7:G_Communication_7:fo_smartControllerActive_b": {
       "metadata": {
           "ServerTimestamp": {
               "type": "ISO8601",
               "value": "2021-05-04T07:38:01.150Z"
           },
           "SourceTimestamp": {
               "type": "ISO8601",
               "value": "2021-05-04T07:37:59.934Z"
           }
       },
       "type": "Boolean",
       "value": false
   },
   "id": "plant",
   "type": "g_communication"
}
```

3. Registrations

```sh
curl 'http://localhost:1026/v2/registrations'  -H 'fiware-service: test' -H 'fiwate-servicepath: /test' | python -m json.tool
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   320  100   320    0     0  46049      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 53333
[
    {
        "dataProvided": {
            "attrs": [
                "7:PLC1_7:G_Communication_7:fi_heartbeat_i"
            ],
            "entities": [
                {
                    "id": "plant",
                    "type": "g_communication"
                }
            ]
        },
        "expires": "2021-06-03T07:37:38.00Z",
        "id": "6090f9c254b918756abf1a7d",
        "provider": {
            "http": {
                "url": "http://iotopcua:4001"
            },
            "legacyForwarding": true,
            "supportedForwardingMode": "all"
        },
        "status": "active"
    }
]
```

4. Test communication with iotopcua

```sh
 curl "http://iotopcua:4001/version"
{"libVersion":"2.12.0-next","port":4001,"baseRoot":"/"}
```

5. Request for update

```sh
curl -X PUT \
  'http://localhost:1026/v2/entities/plant/attrs/7:PLC1_7:G_Communication_7:fi_heartbeat_i?type=g_communication' \
  -H 'content-type: application/json' \
  -H 'fiware-service: test' \
  -H 'fiware-servicepath: /test' \
  -d '{
  "value": 2
  }'
```

6. Log OCB

```sh
from=0.0.0.0 | srv=test | subsrv=/test | comp=Orion | op=logMsg.h[1844]:lmTransactionStart | msg=Starting transaction from 0.0.0.0:54232/v2/entities/plant/attrs/7:PLC1_7:G_Communication_7:fi_heartbeat_i
from=0.0.0.0 | srv=test | subsrv=/test | comp=Orion | op=rest.cpp[874]:servicePathSplit | msg=Service Path 0: '/test'
from=0.0.0.0 | srv=test | subsrv=/test | comp=Orion | op=connectionOperations.cpp[244]:collectionCount | msg=Database Operation Successful (count: { _id.id: "plant", _id.type: "g_communication", _id.servicePath: "/test" })
from=0.0.0.0 | srv=test | subsrv=/test | comp=Orion | op=connectionOperations.cpp[94]:collectionQuery | msg=Database Operation Successful (query: { _id.id: "plant", _id.type: "g_communication", _id.servicePath: "/test" })
from=0.0.0.0 | srv=test | subsrv=/test | comp=Orion | op=connectionOperations.cpp[182]:collectionRangedQuery | msg=Database Operation Successful (query: { query: { $or: [ { contextRegistration.entities.id: "plant", contextRegistration.entities.type: "g_communication" }, { contextRegistration.entities.id: ".*", contextRegistration.entities.isPattern: "true", contextRegistration.entities.type: { $in: [ "g_communication" ] } }, { contextRegistration.entities.id: ".*", contextRegistration.entities.isPattern: "true", contextRegistration.entities.type: { $exists: false } } ], expiration: { $gt: 1620114947 }, contextRegistration.attrs.name: { $in: [ "7:PLC1_7:G_Communication_7:fi_heartbeat_i" ] }, servicePath: "/test" }, orderby: { _id: 1 } })
from=0.0.0.0 | srv=test | subsrv=/test | comp=Orion | op=logMsg.h[1844]:lmTransactionStart | msg=Starting transaction to http://iotopcua:4001//updateContext
from=0.0.0.0 | srv=test | subsrv=/test | comp=Orion | op=httpRequestSend.cpp[550]:httpRequestSendWithCurl | msg=Sending message 4 to HTTP server: sending message of 458 bytes to HTTP server
from=10.1.17.1 | srv=test | subsrv=/test | comp=Orion | op=logMsg.h[1844]:lmTransactionStart | msg=Starting transaction from 10.1.17.1:58162/v1/updateContext
from=10.1.17.1 | srv=test | subsrv=/test | comp=Orion | op=rest.cpp[874]:servicePathSplit | msg=Service Path 0: '/test'
from=10.1.17.1 | srv=test | subsrv=/test | comp=Orion | op=connectionOperations.cpp[94]:collectionQuery | msg=Database Operation Successful (query: { _id.id: "plant", _id.type: "g_communication", _id.servicePath: "/test" })
from=10.1.17.1 | srv=test | subsrv=/test | comp=Orion | op=connectionOperations.cpp[454]:collectionUpdate | msg=Database Operation Successful (update: <{ _id.id: "plant", _id.type: "g_communication", _id.servicePath: "/test" }, { $set: { attrs.7:PLC1_7:G_Communication_7:fi_heartbeat_i_status: { value: "PENDING", type: "commandStatus", mdNames: [], creDate: 1620113858, modDate: 1620114947 }, modDate: 1620114947, lastCorrelator: "2324ca1e-acae-11eb-a4f7-226cad26e2cc" }, $unset: { location: 1, expDate: 1 } }>)
from=10.1.17.1 | srv=test | subsrv=/test | comp=Orion | op=logMsg.h[1874]:lmTransactionEnd | msg=Transaction ended
from=0.0.0.0 | srv=test | subsrv=/test | comp=Orion | op=httpRequestSend.cpp[570]:httpRequestSendWithCurl | msg=Notification Successfully Sent to http://iotopcua:4001//updateContext
from=0.0.0.0 | srv=test | subsrv=/test | comp=Orion | op=httpRequestSend.cpp[579]:httpRequestSendWithCurl | msg=Notification response OK, http code: 200
from=0.0.0.0 | srv=test | subsrv=/test | comp=Orion | op=logMsg.h[1874]:lmTransactionEnd | msg=Transaction ended
```

7. Log OPCUA Client

```sh
time=2021-05-04T07:55:47.191Z | lvl=DEBUG | corr=n/a | trans=n/a | op=IoTAgentNGSI.GenericMiddlewares | msg=Request for path [//updateContext] from [iotopcua:4001]
time=2021-05-04T07:55:47.191Z | lvl=DEBUG | corr=n/a | trans=n/a | op=IoTAgentNGSI.GenericMiddlewares | msg=Body:

{
    "contextElements": [
        {
            "type": "g_communication",
            "isPattern": "false",
            "id": "plant",
            "attributes": [
                {
                    "name": "7:PLC1_7:G_Communication_7:fi_heartbeat_i",
                    "type": "Number",
                    "value": 2
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "updateAction": "UPDATE"
}


time=2021-05-04T07:55:47.193Z | lvl=DEBUG | corr=n/a | trans=n/a | op=IoTAgentNGSI.ContextServer | msg=Handling update from [iotopcua:4001]
time=2021-05-04T07:55:47.193Z | lvl=DEBUG | corr=n/a | trans=n/a | op=IoTAgentNGSI.ContextServer | msg=[object Object]
time=2021-05-04T07:55:47.194Z | lvl=DEBUG | corr=n/a | trans=n/a | op=IoTAgentNGSI.InMemoryGroupRegister | msg=Looking for device params ["service","subservice","type"]
time=2021-05-04T07:55:47.194Z | lvl=DEBUG | corr=n/a | trans=n/a | op=IoTAgentNGSI.DeviceService | msg=deviceData after merge with conf: {"id":"plant","name":"plant","type":"g_communication","active":[{"name":"7:PLC1_7:G_Communication_7:fo_smartControllerActive_b","type":"Boolean","object_id":"7:PLC1_7:G_Communication_7:fo_smartControllerActive_b"}],"service":"test","subservice":"/test","polling":null,"endpoint":"opc.tcp://109.68.106.155:48050","registrationId":"6090f9c254b918756abf1a7d","creationDate":1620113858802}
time=2021-05-04T07:55:47.194Z | lvl=DEBUG | corr=n/a | trans=n/a | op=IoTAgentNGSI.DeviceService | msg=deviceData before merge with conf: {"id":"plant","name":"plant","type":"g_communication","active":[{"name":"7:PLC1_7:G_Communication_7:fo_smartControllerActive_b","type":"Boolean","object_id":"7:PLC1_7:G_Communication_7:fo_smartControllerActive_b"}],"lazy":[],"commands":[{"name":"7:PLC1_7:G_Communication_7:fi_heartbeat_i","type":"Command","object_id":"7:PLC1_7:G_Communication_7:fi_heartbeat_i"}],"service":"test","subservice":"/test","polling":null,"endpoint":"opc.tcp://109.68.106.155:48050","registrationId":"6090f9c254b918756abf1a7d","creationDate":1620113858802,"internalAttributes":null,"staticAttributes":[],"subscriptions":[]}
time=2021-05-04T07:55:47.195Z | lvl=INFO | corr=n/a | trans=n/a | op=Index.CommandContextHandler | comp=iotAgent-OPCUA | srv=test | subsrv=/test | msg=method to call =[{"objectId":"ns=7;s=G_Communication","methodId":"ns=7;s=G_Communication.fi_heartbeat_i","inputArguments":[{"type":"Number"}]}]
time=2021-05-04T07:55:47.879Z | lvl=DEBUG | corr=n/a | trans=n/a | op=IoTAgentNGSI.NGSIService | msg=executeWithDeviceInfo entityName plant type undefined apikey undefined attributes [{"name":"7:PLC1_7:G_Communication_7:fi_heartbeat_i_status","type":"commandStatus","value":"PENDING"}] deviceInformation {"id":"plant","name":"plant","type":"g_communication","active":[{"name":"7:PLC1_7:G_Communication_7:fo_smartControllerActive_b","type":"Boolean","object_id":"7:PLC1_7:G_Communication_7:fo_smartControllerActive_b"}],"lazy":[],"commands":[{"name":"7:PLC1_7:G_Communication_7:fi_heartbeat_i","type":"Command","object_id":"7:PLC1_7:G_Communication_7:fi_heartbeat_i"}],"service":"test","subservice":"/test","polling":null,"endpoint":"opc.tcp://109.68.106.155:48050","registrationId":"6090f9c254b918756abf1a7d","creationDate":1620113858802,"internalAttributes":null,"staticAttributes":[],"subscriptions":[]}
time=2021-05-04T07:55:47.879Z | lvl=DEBUG | corr=n/a | trans=n/a | op=IoTAgentNGSI.NGSIService | msg=error {"name":"DEVICE_GROUP_NOT_FOUND","message":"Couldn\t find device group","code":404} in get group device
time=2021-05-04T07:55:47.880Z | lvl=DEBUG | corr=n/a | trans=n/a | op=IoTAgentNGSI.NGSIService | msg=typeInformation {"id":"plant","name":"plant","type":"g_communication","active":[{"name":"7:PLC1_7:G_Communication_7:fo_smartControllerActive_b","type":"Boolean","object_id":"7:PLC1_7:G_Communication_7:fo_smartControllerActive_b"}],"lazy":[],"commands":[{"name":"7:PLC1_7:G_Communication_7:fi_heartbeat_i","type":"Command","object_id":"7:PLC1_7:G_Communication_7:fi_heartbeat_i"}],"service":"test","subservice":"/test","polling":null,"endpoint":"opc.tcp://109.68.106.155:48050","registrationId":"6090f9c254b918756abf1a7d","creationDate":1620113858802,"internalAttributes":null,"staticAttributes":[],"subscriptions":[]}
time=2021-05-04T07:55:47.880Z | lvl=DEBUG | corr=n/a | trans=n/a | op=IoTAgentNGSI.NGSIService | msg=Updating device value in the Context Broker at [http://orion:1026/v1/updateContext]
time=2021-05-04T07:55:47.880Z | lvl=DEBUG | corr=n/a | trans=n/a | op=IoTAgentNGSI.NGSIService | msg=Using the following request:

{
    "url": "http://orion:1026/v1/updateContext",
    "method": "POST",
    "headers": {
        "fiware-service": "test",
        "fiware-servicepath": "/test"
    },
    "json": {
        "contextElements": [
            {
                "type": "g_communication",
                "isPattern": "false",
                "id": "plant",
                "attributes": [
                    {
                        "name": "7:PLC1_7:G_Communication_7:fi_heartbeat_i_status",
                        "type": "commandStatus",
                        "value": "PENDING"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "updateAction": "UPDATE"
    }
}


time=2021-05-04T07:55:47.886Z | lvl=DEBUG | corr=n/a | trans=n/a | op=IoTAgentNGSI.NGSIService | msg=Received the following request from the CB:

{
    "contextResponses": [
        {
            "contextElement": {
                "type": "g_communication",
                "isPattern": "false",
                "id": "plant",
                "attributes": [
                    {
                        "name": "7:PLC1_7:G_Communication_7:fi_heartbeat_i_status",
                        "type": "commandStatus",
                        "value": ""
                    }
                ]
            },
            "statusCode": {
                "code": "200",
                "reasonPhrase": "OK"
            }
        }
    ]
}


time=2021-05-04T07:55:47.886Z | lvl=DEBUG | corr=n/a | trans=n/a | op=IoTAgentNGSI.NGSIService | msg=Value updated successfully
time=2021-05-04T07:55:47.886Z | lvl=DEBUG | corr=n/a | trans=n/a | op=IoTAgentNGSI.ContextServer | msg=Update action from [iotopcua:4001] handled successfully.
time=2021-05-04T07:55:47.886Z | lvl=DEBUG | corr=n/a | trans=n/a | op=IoTAgentNGSI.ContextServer | msg=Generated update response: {"contextResponses":[{"contextElement":{"attributes":[{"name":"7:PLC1_7:G_Communication_7:fi_heartbeat_i","type":"Number","value":""}],"id":"plant","isPattern":false,"type":"g_communication"},"statusCode":{"code":200,"reasonPhrase":"OK"}}]}
time=2021-05-04T07:55:47.887Z | lvl=DEBUG | corr=n/a | trans=n/a | op=IoTAgentNGSI.DomainControl | msg=response-time: 697
```

Answer (score 0):

as far as i can tell, i think the error resides in your contextSubscription snippet inside your config.json which should look like :

```
"contextSubscriptions": [{
  "id": "plant",
  "type": "g_communication",
  "service": "test",
  "subservice": "/test",
  "mappings": [{
    "ocb_id": "7:PLC1_7:G_Communication_7:fi_heartbeat_i",
    "opcua_id": "ns=7;s=G_Communication.fi_heartbeat_i",
    "object_id": "ns=7;s=G_Communication",
    "inputArguments": [{
      "dataType": 4,
      "type": "Intensity"
    }]
  }]
}]
```

Could you please give it a try?

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work either. I suspect the problem here lies further in the basics. The example from the manual [fiware opcua agent](https://iotagent-opcua.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) that I think you are referring to here writes command values to the data type ExtensionObject.  
In my example I would like to write to a NodeId of basic data type (in my case Int16) with AccessLevel CurrentRead, CurrentWrite. I think the NodId ns=3;s=Speed from the manual would be the best comparable counterpart here.

Comment: I've now understood your scenario, at moment we don't support this kind of feature so you need to implement a proper method on your opcua server and request its call from the iotagent. Referring to previous example, you can't directly edit the speed but you have to invoke the accelerate method to "indirectly" edit it